# FIRSTNOTBLANK (DAX) Power BI - Without Auto-ordering

Tags: powerbi, dax

it seems like `PowerBI` is auto-ordering my `table` and I don't know why. So, I have this table (that I exported from a `Excel` file)

```
Colonne 1
7
25
1
8
3
```

Whenever I do a `New Mesure`, with this formula:

```
Mesure = FIRSTNONBLANK(Feuil1[Colonne 1];0)
```

It gives me the number `1`. If I do `LASTNONBLANK`, it returns me the number `25`. So it clearly auto-order my dataset, but whenever I look in the «Data» tab of the software, I see that my data are ordered the way I want them to be.

Any idea on how to keep the default ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's the exact behavior of `FIRSTNONBLANK()` and `LASTNONBLANK()`. They [iterate the values of a column based on their native sort order (i.e. data type).](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/alternative-use-of-firstnonblank-and-lastnonblank/) Therefore, `FIRSTNONBLANK` would return the smallest number `1` and and `LASTNONBLANK` the largest number `25`. And in general, you cannot make assumptions on sort order of values in a table or in a column when using DAX.

Therefore, my suggestion is that you can explicitly program the logic to find the target value. Say the table is sorted based on date, you can find the key of the earliest/latest date (based on your use case), then lookup the value using the key.

```
Target = 
VAR TargetKey = 
CALCULATE(
    VALUES(Table1[Key]),
    FILTER(
        Table1,
        Table1[Date] = MIN(Table1[Date]) // or MAX(Table1[Date])
    )
)
RETURN
LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[Colonne 1], Table1[Key], TargetKey)
```

[image: dax]

[image: result]

Comment: So there is no way using DAX to have only the first data of the set? (Without having a «Key» column? (Or date)

Comment: @YannChabot DAX won't know how your table is ordered. Therefore as mentioned above, `FIRSTNONBLANK`/`LASTNONBLANK` will assume the order based on the data type of the targeted column. And if that's not what you want, you have to explicitly: 1. Tell DAX how `Colonne 1` is ordered (e.g. Date, another column, key, etc). 2. how to return the first/last row (e.g. 7, based on a key, filter, another DAX, etc).